# Is there a way to compute this antiderivative by u-substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

I started by trying to find an expression for $\int \ln(ax^n + b) dx$ where $a,n,b$ are integers $>0$. So naturally I used integration by parts and arrived at $$x\ln(ax^n + b) - \int \dfrac{ax^{n}}{ax^n + b}dx$$ Is there a way to compute $\int \frac{ax^{n}}{ax^n + b}dx$ by u-substitution or any other method?

Comment: According to Wolfram, there isn't an elementary antiderivative

Comment: hint: add $b-b$ to the numerator. the resulting integral can be straighforwardly solved by partial fractions

Comment: If $n$ is a positive integer, one can factor $ax^n+b$, then use log of a product.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Sorry, but could you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: It is enough to deal with $\log(x^n+c)$. Note that $x^n+c$ can be explicitly factored over the complex numbers, or into a product of linear terms and irreducible quadratics over the reals. So our log is the sum of logs of linears and/or quadratics.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

In some certain cases depending on the powers, you may use [Chebyshev theorem on the integration of binomial differentials](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Chebyshev_theorem_on_the_integration_of_binomial_differentials) for such that integral.

Answer (score 1):

Outline:  With a change of variable we end up integrating $\ln(c(t^n+1))$ for some positive constant $c$, and then we only need to find $\int \ln(t^n+1)\,dt$. It is too early to integrate by parts. Instead, factor $t^n+1$ over the reals.

Depending on whether $n$ is odd or even, we get that $t^n+1$ is $t+1$ times a product of irreducible quadratics, or just a plain product of irreducible quadratics. These irreducible quadratics are all of the shape $t^2-(2\cos\theta)t +1$. The logarithm of this product is a sum of logarithms.

We look at the case $n$ even. The case $n$ odd is similar. So we are integrating terms of the shape $\ln(t^2-(2\cos\theta) t+1)$. The integration by parts procedure suggested in the OP works. It is helpful to first complete the square.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution in which I suppose $n > 0$**

There is a way, but you shall know special functions, like the HyperGeometric Special Function.

Let's collect $ax^n$:

$$\int\frac{ax^n}{ax^n\left(1 + \left(\frac{b}{a}x^{-n}\right)\right)}\ \text{d}x$$

With the help of Geometric Series we find

$$\int\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \left(-\frac{b}{a}x^{-n}\right)^k\ \text{d}x = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)^k\int x^{-kn}\ \text{d}x$$

Integration is trivial, the resulting series is

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)^k \frac{x^{-kn + 1}}{-kn+1}$$

This series does converge to the HyperGeometric Special Function:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)^k \frac{x^{-kn + 1}}{-kn+1} = x\cdot _2F_1\left[1, -\frac{1}{n}, 1 - \frac{1}{n}, -\frac{b}{a}x^{-n}\right]$$

**More on HSF**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function

Comment: this is way to much for all $n\in\mathbb{Q}$ where we can always find the solution in terms of a finite sum. furthermore at least for me it is not obvious how to directly translate ur solution into its final hypergeometric form

Comment: @tired You're right, because it's about special functions and usually they are not well treated and explained in Universities courses. Fortunately I had a proper and high education about Special Functions, so I can use them very well and quickly. To explain how and why the result is that, I'd need pages (that is why I reported the Wikipedia page, AS A START). Also my solution holds for $n > 0$ not only for $n\in\mathbb{Q}$ ^^